# try...catch if a function throws error NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to handle a function if it throws an error: **create.js**

```
function Apple() {
    createDB() //function that saves into db
}
```

**createDB.js**

```
function createDB() {
     const Info = new collection(data)
     Info.save()
}
```

Suppose createDB function throws an error when required field in the db is not present. I want to handle such errors.

I tried:

```
function Apple() {
try{
    createDB()//function that saves into db //if throws error go to catch 
 block
   } catch{
   function that handles error
    }
 }
```

and I also tried:

```
function createDB() {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
if some condition met{
     const Info = new collection(data)
     Info.save()
}else{
    reject(error)
}

  })    
}
```

But it still doesn't goes to the catch block. I'm relatively new to the topic so any suggestions will be really helpful. Basically I want to handle the errors if a function throws error, and it should go to catch block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually not following the correct syntax. Check out the sampe one:

```
try {
  nonExistentFunction();
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
  // expected output: ReferenceError: nonExistentFunction is not defined
  // Note - error messages will vary depending on browser
}
```

Your updated code with try-catch should follow the above syntax:

```
function Apple() {
try{
    createDB()//function that saves into db //if throws error go to catch 
 block
   } catch (error) {
   function that handles error
// here you should log errors or use the logging lib
    }
 }
```

Also, if you are using promises, you can follow this approach:

```
function createDB() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (condition) {
     const Info = new collection(data);
     Info.save().then(data =>{ resolve(data)})
     .catch(e => {console.error(e)}) // handle this promise also
    }
    else {
    reject(error);
    } 
  })    
}
```

Also, you need to understand when to use try-catch block and when to use promises. The try, catch blocks are used to handle exceptions (a type of an error) when the code is synchronous. You should use Promises only for asynchronous functions and nothing else.

Comment: Let's say :

function createDB() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     const Info = new collection(data);
     Info.save().then(data =>{ resolve(data)})
     .catch(e => {console.error(e)}) // handle this promise also
    }
  })    
}

There is no if condition but while saving data there is error how can I handle it.....can I do:
Inside createDB function:


       Info.save().then(data =>{ resolve(data)})
     .catch(reject(error) // handle this promise also

Comment: Even if there is no "if statement", the "Info.save()" returns promise.Now, you can do two things either you "return Info.save()" or using then and catch statement get the values and catch error here. While you  "return Info.save()"  this, you need to .then where createDB() being called: createDB().then(data =>{console.log(data)}).catch(e => {console.error(e)});

Answer (score 0):

> Use this sample piece of code

> Within try block we write our code which we want to execute

> If any error occur controller goes to catch block

> In catch block we also receive error

```
try {
  //Here write your code which you want to execute
    return true
} catch (error) {
     //if there is an any error controller will come into this block and show error 
  console.error(error);
return false
 
}
```